# Stripe sca subscription php and charge automatically

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have implemented the Stripe SCA migration
my serve side code to create payment intent is as follows

```
      $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
            'payment_method' => $requestData['payment_method_id'],
            'amount' => $requestData->amount,
            'currency' => $requestData->currencyIso,
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'confirmation_method' => "manual",
            'confirm' => true,
            'setup_future_usage'=>"off_session",
        ]);
        return $intent;
```

And my js code is as below to create card payment and handle response

```
 stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardElement, {
        billing_details: {name: cardholderName.value}
 })
```

and handle the response:

```
function handleServerResponse(response) {
  if (response.error) {

  } else if (response.requires_action) {

    stripe.handleCardAction(
      response.payment_intent_client_secret
    ).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {

      } else {
        // The card action has been handled
        // The PaymentIntent can be confirmed again on the server
        fetch('https://test.com/server.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({ 
            payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id, 
             amount: amount


          })
        }).then(function(confirmResult) {
            console.log(confirmResult);
          return confirmResult.json();
        }).then(handleServerResponse);
      }
    });
  } 


  }
}

$plan = Plan::create([
                'currency' => $currency,
                'interval' => 'month',
                'product' => $product->id,
                'nickname' => 'Payment Plan for order - ' . $order_id,
                'amount' => $price,
                'metadata' => [
                    'order_number' => $order_id,
                    'bgt_customer_number' => $customer_id,
                ],
            ]);
            $schedule = SubscriptionSchedule::create([
                'customer' => $customer->id,
                'start_date' => 'now',
                'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
                'metadata' => [
                    'local_id' => $order_id,
                    'local_account_id' => $account_id,
                    'local_currency_id' => $currency_id,
                    'local_user_id'=> $user_id,
                    'local_installments_total' => $plan_length,
                    'bgt_customer_number' => $customer_id,
                    'order_number' => $order_id,
                    'invoice_description' => 'Payment Plan for order - ' . $order_id
                ],
                'phases' => [
                    [
                        'items' => [
                            [
                                'plan' => $plan->id,
                            ],
                        ],
                        'collection_method'=> 'charge_automatically',
                        'iterations'=>$plan_length
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
            $metadata = [
                'installments_paid' => '0',
                'installments_total' => $plan_length,
                'local_id' =>$order_id,
                'local_account_id' =>$account_id,
                'local_currency_id' =>$currency_id,
                'subscription_schedule_id' => $schedule->id
            ];

            $subscription_id=$schedule->subscription;
            $result=Subscription::update($subscription_id,
                [
                    'metadata' => $metadata,
                    'default_payment_method' => $paymentMethodParams['payment_method'],
                    'proration_behavior' =>'always_invoice',
                    //Create only after adding payment method id in customer
                ]
            );
```

I am getting the SCA modal for sca cards and workflow is correct.
But what concerns me is testing the subscription created using sca

I tested using 4000000000003220 amd also 424242424242424.. and subscription is created with 3 installments.

The subscription is created with correct installments:
But what concerns me is the subscription first installment is not being charged immediately.
Invoice shows as:

> This draft invoice was generated by a subscription. It can be edited
> until it's automatically finalized in 1 hour.

```
.
```

When I try to complete the charge from stripe dashboard (as a part of test) it shows

> The invoice was finalized, but the customer needs to complete  3D
> Secure  authentication for the payment to succeed. This additional
> step is required by their bank to prevent fraud. 3D Secure emails are
> disabled in your settings, so you'll need to notify the customer
> manually

The invoice failed to capture.
Question:
1: I wanted the first installment or schedule to happen.
How do I accomplish this in staging env. Am I missing any points here in creating subscription or SCA methods?

2: What is really 'confirmation_method' => "manual". Really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Stripe Subscriptions you typically won't be creating Payment Intents yourself.  Instead you'll be creating and interacting with Billing objects like Subscriptions and Invoices.  The Invoices will create the Payment Intents for you.  Stripe has [a guide that walks you through taking payment information and creating a Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price).  If you read through and follow that guide you should be able to build what you want.

To answer your specific questions:

> Question: 1: I wanted the first installment or schedule to happen. How do I accomplish this in staging env. Am I missing any points here in creating subscription or SCA methods?

This is likely because you're creating a Payment Intent and paying that which is unrelated to the Payment Intent belonging to the Invoice of your Subscription.

> 2: What is really 'confirmation_method' => "manual". Really confused.

[The `confirmation_method` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-confirmation_method) controls how a Payment Intent can be confirmed.  However, if you're using Subscriptions and want to support SCA you should ignore this property and instead follow the guide linked above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It answers most of the issues that I came. But new doubt is when you create the subscription with 'expand' => ['subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent'] as in example, it returns payment_intent.But I am creating subscription_schedule with 'expand' => ['subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent']. It returns till latest invoice only. But payment_intent as Null.

Comment: Payment Intents for Invoices aren't created until the Invoice is finalized, and it sounds like your use of Subscription Schedules might be preventing the Invoice from finalizing immediately.  A possible alternative approach would be to listen for [`invoice.finalized` events](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.finalized) and retrieve the Payment Intent after that.